# Azure ML Compute Instance: how to expose an app listening to a port to the outside world?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a Gradio app listening to a specific port, running in an Azure ML Compute Instance. I'm not using Docker, just a basic Python app.

I want to expose that port to the outside world, so that I can visit the compute's url/ip and access the app. Security is not an issue right now. I don't really want to use Docker (I know about custom apps).

Here's what I've tried:

- Punching a hole through the compute's firewall, with `sudo ufw allow <port>`
- Accessing the compute, as follows

  - `http(s)://<compute-ip>:<port>` - times out
  - `https://<compute>.<location>.instances.azureml.ms:<port>` - times out
  - `https://<compute>-<port>.<location>.instances.azureml.ms/` - loads the app, but the  routes don't work so the app errors out (I get `{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}` on anything but the root url)

My question is: **how do I make this work**? Is there a way to configure the compute to allow my routing urls? Or am I stuck using Docker + custom apps?

Comment: does `https://<compute>-8888.<location>.instances.azureml.ms/` show you the Jupyter running on the CI?

Comment: I get the `A Jupyter Server is running` message, but that's it - I can access Jupyter with both `https://<compute>-8888.<location>.instances.azureml.ms/tree` and `https://<compute>.<location>.instances.azureml.ms/tree`.

Comment: The last option https://<compute>-<port>.<location>.instances.azureml.ms/ works for me for streamlit tho